# Export XY motion Tracking data

Tags: export, tracking, motion-capture

Pretty new to blender, and A bit lost.

I am creating a Sand art table similar to [this one](https://www.instructables.com/Easily-Build-a-MACHINE-THAT-DESTROYS-WHAT-IT-CREAT/). It uses a homebrewed Arduino powered CNC to control 2 servo motors, moving a magnet around, which in turn rolls a steel bearing to draw in some sand.

I want to take motion captured data of a double pendulum and use that as the path to draw.

The end goal is GCode by way of SVG, I assume.

I have good tracking data, and can see the XY data and the motion path.

For the live of me I cannot find how to export that data in a way that either fusion 360, adobe illustrator, or even excel can read.

I've tried several tutorials, read several forum posts, but nothing makes enough sense when I try to implement. Between updates to the software, changes in addons, and my own ignorance, it's 50/50 that the problem is me vs the tools I"m trying to use.

I appreciate any help!